# VOLLEY / ANDROID : post request but parameters not received

Tags: java, android, json, post, android-volley

I use volley Android library, I have create post request than send to my server :

```
    JSONArray jsonRequest = new JSONArray();
    for(MyLocation myLocation : ListLocation){
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("serial", myLocation.serial);
            jsonObject.put("longitude", myLocation.longitude);
            jsonObject.put("latitude", myLocation.latitude);
            jsonObject.put("altitude", myLocation.altitude);
            jsonObject.put("accuracy", myLocation.accuracy);
            jsonObject.put("date", myLocation.date);
            jsonRequest.put(jsonObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    JsonArrayRequest stringRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, jsonRequest, 
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            dabAcces.dropTable();
            Log.d(TAG, "dropTable");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (row > MAX_REGISTER_GPS_DATA) {
                Log.d(TAG, "deleteOldestRecord");
                dabAcces.deleteOldestRecord();
            }
        }
    });
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

But when I read my server information, I can see the post array it's empty, however when I verify jsonarray contents, I see variable to json format. Help me plz

```html
[2015-08-13 09:30:39] local.INFO: POST 
[2015-08-13 09:30:39] local.INFO: array ()  
[2015-08-13 09:30:39] local.INFO: GET ------------------------------   
[2015-08-13 09:30:39] local.INFO: array ()  
[2015-08-13 09:30:39] local.INFO: SERVER ------------------------------   
[2015-08-13 09:30:39] local.INFO: array (
  'REDIRECT_STATUS' => '200',
  'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; M17-G903-A Build/JZO54K)',
  'HTTP_HOST' => 'geoloc.com',
  'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'Keep-Alive',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip',
  'CONTENT_LENGTH' => '68921',
  'PATH' => '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
  'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => '<address>Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at geoloc.com Port 80</address> 'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => '<address>Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at geoloc.com Port 80</address>
```

Comment: Basically you cant use POST method for "JsonArrayRequest"
JsonArrayRequest supports GET method as of now,
http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/

Comment: You can use post.. That blog post is outdated..

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `JsonArrayRequest` in volley's [source code](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonArrayRequest.java#L103)

```
public JsonArrayRequest(String url, JSONArray jsonRequest, Listener<JSONArray> listener,
                        ErrorListener errorListener) {
    this(jsonRequest == null ? Method.GET : Method.POST, url, jsonRequest,
            listener, errorListener);
}
```

It means you need to pass a JsonArray not a JsonObject

Comment: I have updated my answer with the updated source code. Please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cant use POST method for **"JsonArrayRequest"**.
JsonArrayRequest class can be used to retrieve JSON array but not JSON object and only **HTTP GET** is supported as of now. As it supports only GET, so if you are to specify some querystring parameters then append those in the URL itself. The constructor does not accept request parameters.

If you want to send data in **post** method, you can use **"JsonObjectRequest"** OR **"StringRequest"**.

Small example to send data in POST method using "StringRequest"

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("param1", "value1");
                params.put("param2","value2");
                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
```

you should override getParams() method to pass the data in POST method. Now you will get your data in the server end.